# Callout accessory view with grey arrow button not blue 'i' button

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I see many examples on how to add a callout accessory view to an annotation:

```
        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
        [rightButton addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

However that gives me a blue info button:

[image]

But I really want the grey arrow button:

[image]

Is there a way to get this type of button from the SDK.  I tried all the button types defined in UIButton, but no luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, detail disclosure button style is not available in iOS7 (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012468/mkannotationview-always-shows-infobutton-instead-of-detaildisclosure-btn).  Instead, use a button with a gray arrow image.  Also, setting the target and action to nil doesn't make sense (implementing the calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method instead of a custom action is generally better anyway).

Answer (score 3):

get an image of arrow and set it in callout accessory view

```
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[rightButton addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```